# Value attribute in textarea bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textarea I use as a form on a website.

I usually use place "*placeholder*" text inside, but I need this information to come up editable.

What I used to do was just feed info from my database into the "*value*" attribute of the form. The form would then just pop up with my data, ready to be edited.

For some reason though its not working with my textarea!

Here is my code:

```
<textarea value='<?php echo $info?>' class="form-control" id="message" name="message"  rows="5"></textarea>
```

I know its not the data because iv echoed it elsewhere and its fine. I also tried

```
<textarea value='hi' class="form-control" id="message" name="message"  rows="5"></textarea>
```

with nothing showing up.

Whats going on ? I used to do this all the time. Im using bootstrap 3, could it have something to do with that ?

Answer (score 14):

`<textarea>` tag doesn't have `value` attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp Content should be placed between opening and closing tags

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"  rows="5">hi</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to put some text in a textarea you should write something like

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"  rows="5">hi</textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"  rows="5">
     <?php echo $info ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: @YannDìnendal It's not specially the yours, just when I see the original post and what it has become, I prefer rollback to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

text area does not have value, put the text between opening and closing tags for example

```
<textarea name="myText">
this is text area
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<textarea name="message"  rows="5">
    <?php echo $variable_or_any_php_code?; >
</textarea>
```

Comment: and your php statement is also have an error.. make sure to correct it too.